# Unable to add bibliography to llncs file

Tags: bibliographies, lncs

I am getting the following error while trying to run `Latex`, followed by `Bibtex`, and then twice `Latex`. I am doing this on Texmaker on Linux.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \bibname
\@mkboth {\sl \uppercase {\bibname }}{\sl \uppercase {\b...
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{10}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@listctr
l.5 \bibitem{altman2005ranking}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
! You can't use `\relax' after \the.
<recently read> \c@
l.5 \bibitem{altman2005ranking}
I'm forgetting what you said and using zero instead.
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@listctr
```

However, the PDF generates, with the following issues.

1. The Biliography is added to the PDF, but in an improper format. I am trying to use the square bracket numbered system, where the references appear in text as "[2]", and, under references, as "[2] Altman, A., Tennenholtz, M.: Ranking systems: the pagerank axioms. In:
   Proceedings of the 6th ACM conference on Electronic commerce. pp. 1--8. ACM
   (2005)"
   In my case, however, the references are just pushed into the PDF as below, without any numbering:
   [image]
2. Additionally, the biblio items are not referenced in the text correctly. All the references are showing up as "(0)"
   [image]

My Latex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{llncs}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{spverbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{bera}

\begin{document}

 Text goes here. References call by \cite{altman2005ranking}.

\section{References}
\bibliographystyle{splncs03}
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

The bbl file is as follows:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\providecommand{\url}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\providecommand{\urlprefix}{URL }

\bibitem{altman2005ranking}
Altman, A., Tennenholtz, M.: Ranking systems: the pagerank axioms. In: Proceedings of the 6th ACM conference on Electronic commerce. pp. 1--8. ACM (2005)
\end{thebibliography}
```

Finally, the last few lines of the aux file are:

```
\bibdata{example}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {5}References}{8}}
\bibcite{altman2005ranking}{0}
\bibcite{amato2013decentralized}{0}
\bibcite{amato2014planning}{0}
\bibcite{gmytrasiewicz2004interactive}{0}
\bibcite{gosavi2014simulation}{0}
\bibcite{howard1960dynamic}{0}
\bibcite{kaelbling1998planning}{0}
\bibcite{kaelbling1996reinforcement}{0}
\bibcite{parkes2013dynamic}{0}
\bibcite{pineau2003point}{0}
\bibcite{puterman2014markov}{0}
\bibcite{sondik1971optimal}{0}
\bibcite{tennenholtz2004dynamic}{0}
\bibcite{undurti2010online}{0}
\bibcite{wiering2007computing}{0}
```

The bib file has a sample attached below:

```
@inproceedings{amato2013decentralized,
title={Decentralized control of partially observable Markov decision processes},
author={Amato, Christopher and Chowdhary, Girish and Geramifard, Alborz and {\"U}re, N Kemal and Kochenderfer, Mykel J},
booktitle={52nd IEEE Conference on Decision and Control},
pages={2398--2405},
year={2013},
organization={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{pineau2003point,
title={Point-based value iteration: An anytime algorithm for POMDPs},
author={Pineau, Joelle and Gordon, Geoff and Thrun, Sebastian and others},
year={2003}
}
```

Has anyone else faced these issues? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please reduce your example to the minimal example that still has this issue. Remove also the outdated packages `subfigure` and `epsfig`. And please show your `example.bib` file as well. `fixltx2e` is also not needed any longer since April 2015 (assuming an up-to-date TeX distribution of course!)

Comment: Hi, Christian, I've done the required. However, compiling the document now returns additional errors. I'm getting an undefined control sequence for `\subfigtopskip` and a few others. Also, a "missing \begin{document}", somehow.

Comment: Well, as I said: reduce it to the minimal version that still has the original error! This means: Kick the figures etc. out.

Comment: Surprisingly, I stumbled onto the solution while trying to do this. It seems the package `\apalike` that I was including was causing the issue. Removing the same fixed the issue for me. I'll add that as an answer and close this post.

Comment: Also `pslatex` is obsolete. If you want Times for your main font, change that into `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` or (not recommended, but needed if you have an old TeX distribution) `\usepackage{mathptmx}`.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this issue because of this line:

```
\usepackage{apalike}
```

Since I'm relatively new to Latex, I think what was happening here was that, this package was colliding with the bibliography templates and style files provided by the LNCS zip package. Removing the same allowed the PDF to be generated without any errors.

I thank @ChristianHupfer for his suggestion in the comments of this post.

Comment: To help latex beginners to work on LNCS, I started a template containing the most important packages at https://latextemplates.github.io/LNCS/.